# Connecting to on-prem SQL Server through Azure Databricks

Tags: sql-server, azure-databricks

Does Azure Databricks support connecting to on-premises SQL Server ?

Comment: [Yes, per the documentation](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/spark/latest/data-sources/index.html) via JDBC drivers that [come with Databricke Runtime 3.4 and above](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/spark/latest/data-sources/sql-databases.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the JDBC drivers as scsimon suggested.

However, unless your database is accessible to the internet it will be unable to connect.

To resolve this you need to vnet attach your databricks workspace to a vnet that has VPN or ExpressRoute connectivity to your onprem site (and correct routing in place). This is currently a preview feature that you will need to contact Microsoft to get enabled.

Full details here: https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/administration-guide/cloud-configurations/azure/vnet-inject.html

Comment: This is indeed what I was looking for. Hope this feature GA's soon. Thanks a lot Simon.