# To connect to an on premise database from MS Azure notebook via API call

Tags: database, azure, api

I would like to connect to an on-premise database (say SQL Server) from Azure Databricks notebook, via REST API Call. Also, I would like to perform an UPSERT operation on a table in the database from the same. 
Is it possible?
Kindly upload the necessary steps.

Comment: My suggestion is that you do a little bit of research before posting a very broad question. Just google it and you can end up with this official documentation:[Connect your Azure Databricks Workspace to your on-premises network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/cloud-configurations/azure/on-prem-network)

Comment: Hi Palash Lad, welcome to stack overflow. If my answer is helpful for you, you can mark it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you and have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JDBC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) to connect to an on-premise database (say SQL Server) from Azure Databricks notebook.

You could reference this Azure document: [SQL Databases using JDBC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/sql-databases):

- This article covers how to use the DataFrame API to connect to SQL
  databases using JDBC and how to control the parallelism of reads
  through the JDBC interface. This article provides detailed examples
  using the Scala API, with abbreviated Python and Spark SQL examples
  at the end.

You also could reference the document [Connect your Azure Databricks Workspace to your on-premises network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/cloud-configurations/azure/on-prem-network) @Sebastian Inones provided in the comment.

Ref this here: [Connecting to on-prem SQL Server through Azure Databricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54244249/connecting-to-on-prem-sql-server-through-azure-databricks)

Hope this helps.